# input area Chrome and Firefox behave different

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I have an input area:

```
<input class="input-large" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="5" size="5" autofocus>
```

css for this input:

```
              .input-large{

                position: absolute;
                width: 600px;
                margin: 0 auto;

                font-size: 150px;
                text-align: left;
                border: 1;
                letter-spacing: 38px;

            }
```

I want to achieve this: User can input maximum 5 numbers, if exceeded 5 numbers, the input box stops to show the rest numbers.

When I test it on Firefox, it is fine. However, when I test it on Chrome, Chrome has a yellow focus rectangle which is fine, but when I put in more than 5 numbers, the previous numbers are shifting left bit, they are not stayed fixed like they are like in Firefox.

Anyone knows how to turn off this features of Chrome?

-------------------------------update------------------------------------------

I solved this issue by setting the DIVs all absolute, and wider. This input field is just inside another div. Previously, the outside div is relative. Then I changed back to absolute and adjust the margin. everything works fine now.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue in my Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95m (Windows). <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/KkMWq/">jsFiddle</a>

Comment: Hi Harshad, thank you for your reply. As this problem was just a part from a whole website, I think different div has some effect with each other. In the end, I changed the position to "fixed" and make the input field wider, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the yellow focus rectangle is from an `outline`. just set: `outline: none;` to get rid of it

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt reply. Just as I said, yellow is fine, but the numbers are bouncing left a little bit when input exceed the 5 numbers. In Mozilla, if input exceed 5 numbers, the first five numbers are stay fixed, but in Chrome, the numbers are bouncing left a little bit after exceed 5 numbers... any solution for that?

Comment: @RobertChang I don't think so, that is expected behavior. It pushes the numbers to the left because if you were typing, you need to see what you're typing. you're saying if the input is bigger than the input field, you only want to show the first numbers and cut off the rest? either way, the input will be cut off, the only solution would be to make the input field bigger.

Comment: Hi kennpy, I found the problem was caused by other div. I make the div which contain this input field wider and position absolute, then problem solved.